# What are locker-service requirements that my app should follow

Tags: locker-service

I have developed an app it works fine. But then I integrate my app in `salesforce` while `locker-service active` it gives error.

I have `"use strict"` statement in my app it helped me rectify some errors but `"use strict"` does not tell all errors. Each time I have to put my app in salesforce get bug, fix it put it again in `salesforce`.

Comment: Here is some documentation on LockerService: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm?search_text=lockerservice.  The highlights being strict mode, CSP compliance (no unsafe-eval or unsafe-inline), and only touching areas of the DOM that your own namespace has created. Was there anything specific you wanted more info on?

Comment: @TrevorBliss Thanks for you support. One more thing I need to know why `salesforce` is not providing implementation of these methods `getComputedTextLength` , `getTotalLength`, `getTotalLength` when locker-service enabled [referring to my this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164429/document-getelementbyidmyid-getcomputedtextlength-is-not-a-function)